# How to force npm publish to include files (that are not required by the entry)?

Tags: npm

I have an npm project for generating packages.  It contains a folder called templates.  The files in templates are not required by the entry point index.js instead they are collected using fs. They are not appearing in the published version.  I have tried adding files: ["templates"] to the package.json (and various combinations ("templates/*", "templates/**/*", "templates/something/somefile.js") but the files are never included.  The only files in templates folder that appear are Licence and package.json.

How do I make npm include these files in the published version?

**Edit:** My project directory has a `.gitignore` file but that does not include the `templates` folder. It does not have an `.npmignore` file.

Comment: Unless you provide small project through which issue can be reproduced, it will be hard to find any root cause.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the License and package.json files are appearing in your templates folder, is because npm ignores any attempt to exclude these files.

I would check that you don’t have any .ignore files in your templates folder and also check further up the filesystem, does the folder that contains your project have one? What about it’s parent and so on?

Then try temporarily removing the .gitignore file as well.

Lastly try publishing from another machine if nothing else works.